# iOS Swift Parse- Call parse cloud function after force-quitting an app

Tags: ios, swift, parse-platform

I'm trying to call a Parse cloud code function from the applicationWillTerminate function call, but I think they app

```
func applicationWillTerminate(_ application: UIApplication) {
    // Called when the application is about to terminate. Save data if appropriate. See also applicationDidEnterBackground:.
    // Saves changes in the application's managed object context before the application terminates.
    PFCloud.callFunction(inBackground: "deleteRoom", withParameters: ["roomid" : roomid as Any])
}
```

I tried using the default hello world function that just prints 'hello', but no results.

How can I keep the cloud function call running before the app terminates or maybe even after it terminates?

Comment: FYI - `applicationWillTerminate` is not called when an app is force-quit.

Answer (score 0):

You cant run code after the app is closed. You can Managing State Transitions. Check out https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate